# Unity android build error after upload project to new version

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

i have a problem, so i moved the unity project from version 2018.2.20f1 to version 2019.1.9f1 which has "andorid support something installed" and wanted to build a game for android, but i have such problems:
(I have JDK and SDK installed together with unity)
photos:
[installed with unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gmQ5.png)

[Errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHQRN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your project folder so that it contain only ASCII characters, regular Arabic letters, for ex. "MyProject" and see if that helps.

Comment: But my project has only ASCII characters

Comment: it says in the error console that is has non-ASCII characters, double check within the project folder itself too.

Comment: okey thanks men, I pay honor. in my project name i had: ' char. IT WORKS!

Comment: @Anonymous Glad that I could help, just don't forget to mark this answer as a correct one so the issue can be closed